# How do I insert image into mongodb using angularjs, nodejs using mongojs module

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, mongojs

I want to upload images using angularjs and inserting that image into database using node js module mongojs

How to make schema using mongojs for upload image and inserting images into database using mongojs module?

Comment: You can't ask us to write the code for you. If you have a specific problem please add your code to be reviewed.

Comment: I am new to nodejs I want to insert image into mongodb.. I am using mean stack in my application this is my api cal to insert document into mongodb              " server.post('/api/v1/Insight/auth/register', function (req, res, next) {    var user = req.params;      db.appUsers.insert(user,
                function (err, dbUser) {
                                  res.writeHead(200, {
                            'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
                        });"

Comment: I am getting data from front end using angualrjs I want to upload image using  angularjs and store it into mongodb....